# While generating Controller, "View Model "requires a primary key" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have 3 tables, 1 has master data of students, 1 is a lookup table that links address and third is a table of family members names.

I wanted to create a page to input student details, their address and family members. So I created a View model class.

When I generate the Controller for that view model class, The Entity type "ViewModelClassName" requires a primary key error pops up.

I am new to web development. I am in a situation where there is no one to ask anything. Please help. Thanks.

```
public StudentMaster StudentMaster { get; set; }        
public StudentAddresses StudentAddresses { get; set; }
public StudentFamilyMembers StudentFamilyMembers { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you share StudentMaster, StudentAddresses class ?

Comment: **StudentMaster**
public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Rating { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    public ICollection<StudentAddresses> StudentAddresses { get; set; }
    public StudentFamilyMembers StudentFamilyMembers { get; set; }

**StudentAddresses**
    public int StudentAddressId { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public StudentMaster StudentMaster { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public AddressMaster AddressMaster { get; set; }

Comment: If you observe, you given StudentId in studentadresses table. without primarykey providing, relationship between tables cant be set. Try to give [Key] attribute on the primary key field. for ex: [Key] public int StudentId{get; set;}

Comment: @sriharsha I am trying to paste this as code. Please bare with me am a complete newbie to this.

Comment: I have set that attribute in a separate class and set StudentAddressId as primary key using fluent api.
     builder.HasKey(e => e.StudentAddressId);

Comment: @sriharsha I have set StudentId as the primary key. To define the relationship I have added Icollection at **studentmaster** table, and linked it. Is that not correct?
Tx

Comment: set for studentaddresses table also studentaddressid as primary key. and try

Comment: We can only have 1 primary key right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Scaffolding is expecting **Entity Framework based Data Model** classes in order to help you creating views/controllers . But you are using View Model ,view model doesn't been persist in a database and also it doesn't have any primary key field, hence it cannot be scaffolded. And also when using scaffold wizard you always need to choose data context . But a view model has no relationship with your data context.

You should use your actual data model instead of a viewmodel to perform scaffolding , then modify the codes to use view model to transfer data between views and controllers

Inside your controller action that you could map the view model back to your data model that will be persisted using EF. You could use [AutoMapper](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/09/23/using-automapper-asp-net-core/) to map between your view models and data models.